# <Int> == <String>

Tags: scala, types

Why can I compare an Int and a String in Scala with ==, like `1=="2"`, even when this Operator is not defined for a String in the API (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Int)?

Comment: Note that the compiler will warn you: "warning: comparing values of types Int and String using `==' will always yield false". There are a number of ways to prevent comparisons of unequal types altogether. For example http://www.scalautils.org/ ; I also wrote a small macro: https://github.com/Sciss/Equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's defined in `Any`: [`def ==(arg0: Any): Boolean`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Any@==(Any):Boolean)

> Test two objects for equality. The expression x == that is equivalent to if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that).

Comment: To see this in the docs, you need to click Inherited: "Any" at the top of the scaladoc. For clarity, it's de-selected by default.